# Struck to play URL videos using VideoView in android

Tags: android, video

Hi i am new for android in my app i am using VideoView for playing URL videos

But using my below code URL video is not buffering properly 
and stuck to play 
please help me how can play URL videos perfectly with out stuck

Need to follow Asynchronous process then please explain me with some code

### code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar progressBar = null;
    VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/android_book/movie.mp4");

        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mVideoView.start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, you missed requestfocus to VideoView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar progressBar = null;
    VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/android_book/movie.mp4");

        mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
       // Request focus was missing         
        videoview.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mVideoView.start();
            }
        });

    } }
```

Comment: what do u mean is it solution to my problem?

Comment: Try to add  videoview.requestFocus();

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is download video for first time like shown in below,

My suggestion is download video for first time like shown in below,

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;


public class VideoSaveSDCARD extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ProgressBack PB = new ProgressBack();
        PB.execute("");
    }

    private class ProgressBack extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
         ProgressDialog PD;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            PD= ProgressDialog.show(LoginPage.this,null, "Please Wait ...", true);
            PD.setCancelable(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        downloadFile("http://beta-vidizmo.com/hilton.mp4","Sample.mp4");            

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            PD.dismiss();

        }

    }



    private void downloadFile(String fileURL, String fileName) {
        try {
        String rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Video";
           File rootFile = new File(rootDir);
           rootFile.mkdir();
            URL url = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            //Updated Code.
            File videoFile = new File(rootFile, fileName); // always maintain single Video File.
            if(videoFile.exists())//check already exists
                videoFile.delete();// then delete it.
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream();
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Error....", e.toString());
    }

}
```

Then start playing from external storage

Comment: i think it's not correct way,Suppose if i have list of videos every time video download and playing,Is it not memory waste ?

Comment: youtube also done that, if you click particular video, it will download each frame buffer then only you able to reback it.

Comment: if we tapped on bunch of videos then that all videos download in our device then it's memory waste right?

Comment: No, i.e, you have listview having each video thumnail, when you click particular video simply start new activity with videoview. download it and play it,if user back pressed delete that one .

Comment: check above code, if file already exist delete that one and create new one that same name.

Comment: so this File videoFile = new File(rootFile, fileName); is my final downloadable video file the how can i play this file?

Comment: i am new for android please explain detail

Comment: Uri video = Uri.parse(videoFile.getAbsolutePath()); , pass this uri to your videoview